# Hats this year?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

I loved the Hats from the past couple of years. I thought it would be happening by now, but I could be wrong. Is there a "Hats" season on SU this year? The earlier questions about participation started in Nov.

Comment: It's hatmas now: http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Well, hats are opt *out*, and we didn't opt out.

There'll be hats this [hatmas](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Cat hats?! plez

Comment: No idea what hats there will be ;p